# How to perform a sql count based on a foreign key

Tags: mysql, count, foreign-keys

Here is the simplified schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `person` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `HousingId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `housing` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Capacity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
);
```

**How can I simply get the free space for each housing ?**

I tried the following query:

```
select housing.Id, housing.Capacity - count(person.Id)
from housing, person 
where person.HousingId = housing.Id 
group by housing.Id
```

But it works only for housing having at least one person, not for empty ones.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: which SQL?mysql,mssql,sqllite

Comment: I am using mysql, but the question should be valid whatever the DB system.

Comment: try building that schema in SQLfiddle to test it and then tell me that...

Comment: Edited schema creation queryies to work with SQLFiddle :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a outer join

```
select housing.Id, housing.Capacity - count(person.Id)
from housing
LEFT OUTER JOIN person ON person.HousingId = housing.Id 
group by housing.Id, housing.Capacity
```

Comment: The query is working but I still never get empty housings ("0" in second field)

Comment: I think `housing.Capacity` in the `GROUP BY` clause is redundant.

Comment: Maybe, my background is from MSSQL.

Comment: My bad, I cleaned my data and rebuilt a complete new data set. Now it is working. Sorry for the mess and thank you for your help !